# How to get the range of characters that are visible from within -textStorageDidProcessEditing:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax-highlighting, appkit, nslayoutmanager

For my syntax highlighting implementation, I observe changes to an `NSTextView` using `-[<NSTextStorageDelegate> textStorageDidProcessEditing:]`.

```
- (void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if (!self.languageGrammar) return;
  NSTextStorage *textStorage = self.textView.textStorage;
  NSRange glyphRange = [self.textView.layoutManager glyphRangeForBoundingRect:self.scrollView.documentVisibleRect
                                                              inTextContainer:self.textView.textContainer];
  NSRange editedRange = [self.textView.layoutManager characterRangeForGlyphRange:glyphRange actualGlyphRange:NULL];

  [textStorage removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:editedRange];
  // crash is the line above ^^^^
  // color text ...
}
```

I want to get the range of visible characters. The above code works until I hit <kbd>backspace</kbd>, which makes it crash:

```
*** -[NSConcreteTextStorage attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

How would I get the range of visible characters so I can color them?

Comment: What's the value of `editedRange` at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the range is beyond the bounds of the entire string, and if it is set the range to fit the bounds of the string:

```
NSRange range = NSRangeFromString(string);
```